# Get data from the database in small parts in C#

Tags: c#, database, loops

In my C# application, I have a stored procedure which returns some kind of data from the database. The input parameters which I pass to the procedure are start date, end date and a such called "number of lines" parameter. Each line represents an entry in the database. Due to the database call restrictions I can't pass more than 5000 lines to the procedure per a call. That's why I want to create a some kind of loop to send 5000 lines, get the corresponding data, then another 5000 lines, etc, until I get an output of lines less than 5000 which would mean that there are no more lines left. Could anybody help me with an idea on how this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Care to elaborate? is number of lines output or input parameter?, is the stored procedure a CLR (.NET) procedure or a T-SQL one? Why do you have to retrieve rows 5000 at a time, that doesn't make a lot of sense (there maybe better solutions for the few causes I can think of)

Comment: Your question is not clear; a "line" here sounds like a row in the result set, but then you talk of sending "lines" to the procedure.

Comment: It is a .NET procedure. The number of lines parameter is both an input and output parameter. I have to retrieve 5000 rows at a time as I will get a timeout issue if I pass more. I want to get all the rows within that time range. That's why I want to pass 5000 lines at a time to get all the lines from the database within that time range.

Comment: can't you just raise the time limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only one possible solution for you - you should select your data by primary key. The DBMS will return data ordered by primary key. You should remember key with "maximum value" and at next time you should add condition PK > "maximum value", where PK is primary key. This will force DBMS to return to you next package of data, size of the package you can regulate by "number of lines" as previously

**[EDIT]**
I cant provide code sample because of I actually never work with DB in C#. But this fact didnt eliminate that DBMS always sorts table primary key. For example you have table with next columns:

- ID (int) [PK]
- DATA (CHAR255)

In this table ID is a primary key. So you may do simething like below (pesudo code):

```
< declaration of array which will hold you data from DB > - intTab

SELECT * FROM < your DB tab > UP TO 5000 ROWS
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE intTab
    WHERE < your conditions > 
      AND ID > 0.
```

This `SELECT` would return to you "first" 5000 rows from table. "first" means first rows in index by primary key. To select next 5000 rows you should do:

```
var maxID = < max id from intTab >

SELECT * FROM < your DB tab > UP TO 5000 ROWS
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE intTab
    WHERE < your conditions > 
      AND ID > maxID.
```

This select will return "next" 5000 rows due `ID > maxID` condition.

Comment: That's understandable. But how do I organize this into a loop? A code sample would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could do with [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) to supply data to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure implements paging, you could do it like this:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> StoredProcedure()
{
    var results = new List<IList<SomeType>>();

    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var result = StoredProcedure(i, pageSize);
        i += pageSize;
        results.Add(result);
        if (result.Count == 0)
            break;
    }

    return results.SelectMany(r => r);
}
```